# Expanded data table repeating values in primefaces

Tags: hibernate, jsf, primefaces

I'm having one problem, if I use `createAlias` of `Hibernate`, my `datatable` repeat values, but if I don't use it, it doesn't show repeated values.

My page code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<ui:composition 
    template="/template/common/pagelayout.xhtml" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:ez="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite" 
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/facelets/tags">

    <ui:define name="content">
        <div id="content">

            <f:metadata>
                <f:event listener="#{emitenteListBean.helper.fillDefaults()}" type="preRenderView" />
            </f:metadata>

            <br />

            <div class="form_title">
                <span class="active"> <p:outputLabel value="Filtro de Notas Fiscais"/> </span>
            </div>
            <br />

            <h:form id="list">

                <p:messages id="messages"/>

                <p:panelGrid styleClass="panelGridCenter noBorders">

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnRight">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Emitente"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{emitenteListBean.filter.emitente}" label="Emitente" converter="emitenteConverter" filter="true" filterMatchMode="contains">
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true"/>
                                <f:selectItems var="emitente" value="#{emitenteListBean.listaEmitentes}" itemLabel="#{emitente.dadosEmpresa.cnpj} - #{emitente.dadosEmpresa.razaoSocial}"/>
                            </p:selectOneMenu>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnRight">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Numero da Nota Fiscal"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:inputText maxlength="10" size="15" value="#{emitenteListBean.filter.numeroNota}" onkeypress="mascara(this,soNumeros)"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <p:row>
                        <p:column styleClass="columnRight">
                            <p:outputLabel value="Data de Emissão da Nota Fiscal"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column>
                            <p:calendar locale="pt_BR" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy"  label="Data de Emissão da Nota Fiscal"  value="#{emitenteListBean.filter.dataEmissaoNota}"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:row>

                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <p:row>
                            <p:column colspan="2">
                                <div align="right">
                                    <p:commandButton value="Filtrar" actionListener="#{emitenteListBean.buscar}" update="tabela messages" ajax="false"/>
                                </div>
                            </p:column>
                        </p:row>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panelGrid>

                <br/>
                <div class="form_title">
                    <span class="active"> <p:outputLabel value="Notas Fiscais Cadastradas"/> </span>
                </div>

                <br/><br/>

                <p:dataTable

                    id="tabela"
                    var="emitente"
                    value="#{emitenteListBean.lazyModel}"
                    emptyMessage="Nenhum emitente cadastrado"
                    lazy="true"
                    rows="10"
                    paginator="true"
                    paginatorPosition="bottom"
                    paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                    rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">

                    <f:facet name="header">  
                        <h:outputText value="Notas Fiscais por Emitente"/>
                    </f:facet>

                    <p:column style="width:2%">
                        <p:rowToggler/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Razão Social - CNPJ"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{emitente.dadosEmpresa.razaoSocial} - #{emitente.dadosEmpresa.cnpj}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="Quantidade de Notas Fiscais"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{emitente.notasFiscais.size()}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:rowExpansion>

                        <p:dataTable
                            id="tabelaNotasFiscais" 
                            value="#{emitente.notasFiscais}" 
                            styleClass="noBorders"
                            var="notaFiscal" 
                            lazy="true" 
                            emptyMessage="Nenhuma nota fiscal está cadastrada." 
                            rows="#{emitente.notasFiscais.size()}">

                            <p:column headerText="Numero da Nota Fiscal">
                                <h:outputText value="#{notaFiscal.numero}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Série da Nota Fiscal">
                                <h:outputText value="#{notaFiscal.serie}"/>
                            </p:column>

                            <p:column headerText="Data de Emissão">
                                <h:outputText value="#{notaFiscal.dataEmissao}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>

                        </p:dataTable>

                    </p:rowExpansion>

                </p:dataTable>

                <br />
                <br />

            </h:form>

        </div>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

My dao code:

```
@Override
protected Criteria setUpCriteria(Criteria criteria, FilterNfeHost filter) {

    if (!NullUtil.isNull(filter) && filter instanceof EmitenteFilter) {

        EmitenteFilter filtro = (EmitenteFilter) filter;
        criteria.createAlias("pojo.notasFiscais", "nf");

        return CriterionFactory.getInstance(criteria)
            .eq("pojo.id", NullUtil.isNull(filtro.getEmitente()) ? null : filtro.getEmitente().getId())
            .eq("nf.numero", filtro.getNumeroNota())
            .eq("nf.dataEmissao", filtro.getDataEmissaoNota())
            .getCriteria();
    }

    return criteria;    
}
```

So my register are repeting...

I understand the problem  but I don´t know how to solve this problem, If I have one register repeating six times, it will show for six times.

I have a relationship one to many...

My sql hibernate code

```
Hibernate: 
select
this_.id as id1_4_6_,
this_.cnae as cnae2_4_6_,
this_.dados_empresa_id as dados_em6_4_6_,
this_.inscricao_estadual_substituto_tributario as inscrica3_4_6_,
this_.inscricao_municipal as inscrica4_4_6_,
this_.nome_fantasia as nome_fan5_4_6_,
dadosempre3_.id as id1_2_0_,
dadosempre3_.cnpj as cnpj2_2_0_,
dadosempre3_.cpf as cpf3_2_0_,
dadosempre3_.endereco_id as endereco6_2_0_,
dadosempre3_.inscricao_estadual as inscrica4_2_0_,
dadosempre3_.razao_social as razao_so5_2_0_,
endereco4_.id as id1_5_1_,
endereco4_.bairro as bairro2_5_1_,
endereco4_.cep as cep3_5_1_,
endereco4_.complemento as compleme4_5_1_,
endereco4_.logradouro as logradou5_5_1_,
endereco4_.municipio as municipi6_5_1_,
endereco4_.numero as numero7_5_1_,
endereco4_.telefone as telefone8_5_1_,
endereco4_.uf as uf9_5_1_,
notasfisca1_.id as id1_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.arquivo_nota_fiscal_id as arquivo15_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.chave_nfe as chave_nf2_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.data_emissao as data_emi3_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.data_hora_entrada_ou_saida_produto as data_hor4_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.descricao_natureza_operacao as descrica5_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.destinatario_id as destina16_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.digest_value as digest_v6_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.emitente_id as emitent17_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.finalidade_emissao as finalida7_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.identificador_processo_emissao as identifi8_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.numero as numero9_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.serie as serie10_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.tipo_emissao as tipo_em11_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.tipo_operacao as tipo_op12_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.valor_icms as valor_i13_6_2_,
notasfisca1_.valor_nota_fiscal as valor_n14_6_2_,
arquivonot6_.id as id1_0_3_,
arquivonot6_.conteudo as conteudo2_0_3_,
arquivonot6_.data_registro as data_reg3_0_3_,
arquivonot6_.nome as nome4_0_3_,
destinatar7_.id as id1_3_4_,
destinatar7_.dados_empresa_id as dados_em4_3_4_,
destinatar7_.email as email2_3_4_,
destinatar7_.inscricao_suframa as inscrica3_3_4_,
emitente8_.id as id1_4_5_,
emitente8_.cnae as cnae2_4_5_,
emitente8_.dados_empresa_id as dados_em6_4_5_,
emitente8_.inscricao_estadual_substituto_tributario as inscrica3_4_5_,
emitente8_.inscricao_municipal as inscrica4_4_5_,
emitente8_.nome_fantasia as nome_fan5_4_5_ 
from
emitente this_ 
left outer join
dados_empresa dadosempre3_ 
on this_.dados_empresa_id=dadosempre3_.id 
left outer join
endereco endereco4_ 
on dadosempre3_.endereco_id=endereco4_.id 
inner join
nota_fiscal notasfisca1_ 
on this_.id=notasfisca1_.emitente_id 
left outer join
arquivo_nota_fiscal arquivonot6_ 
on notasfisca1_.arquivo_nota_fiscal_id=arquivonot6_.id 
left outer join
destinatario destinatar7_ 
on notasfisca1_.destinatario_id=destinatar7_.id 
left outer join
emitente emitente8_ 
on notasfisca1_.emitente_id=emitente8_.id limit ?
```

So whats the problem?

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is in JSF/PrimeFaces? It's merely the data presenter here. If the obtained/provided data is in first place wrong, there's nothing which JSF/PrimeFaces can do against.

Comment: I saw the date in the list, and it´s correct...I didn´t told it was primefaces, I don´t know whats wrong but when I use createAlias from Hibernate i got this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using an natural join like condition by creating criteria. try printing out the actual executed SQL query (by adding the sql print as true in config.xml) , so user could see the actual executed query..

i.e.,

- alias is created for an field of the table (pojo.notasFiscais", "nf")
- the table id is used in criteria ("pojo.id") a
- along with the alias
  ("nf.numero" & "nf.dataEmissao")

the user expects the translation to be straight forward

- Replace the alias with the table name & execute the query

but the translation happens other way around, it's negotiated to the translatorfactory implementation, which don't behave as expected.

- it interprets as natural join

**suggestion**: use the field name instead of the alias.

Comment: have you seen the transformation.... it has joined the same entity  twice "emitente"....  can you try running this query in sql IDE and see what you're getting (you'll get duplicates)

Comment: @user2283439 have you seen the transformation.... it has joined the same entity  twice "emitente"....  can you try running this query in sql IDE and see what you're getting (you'll get duplicates).. so either don't use the alias as suggested (which may not work) or use the distinct condition... (as suggested by @jhadesdev).... the conclusion is the query is the problem, not jsf

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to filter for unique results using this result transformer:

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: The lazyMode of the primefaces grid would not cause the duplicates, it seems it's a problem with the query, and the transformer bellow eliminates duplicates in the query.